# ntpd refuses to sync with upstream servers

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I am running ntpd on a CentOS 6.9 server and my configuration for ntpd had been working without issue previously. Typically, it takes a little time but it will sync up with an higher stratum server after a period of time.

However, after I performed a kernel update last night, the server refuses to connect to any of them. It still shows everything besides the local peer as stratum 16.

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 69.164.198.192  .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 198.55.111.50   .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 216.218.254.202 .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 162.210.111.4   .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

I am using the following servers in the config.

```
server 0.north-america.pool.ntp.org
server 1.north-america.pool.ntp.org
server 2.north-america.pool.ntp.org
server 3.north-america.pool.ntp.org
```

ntpd is configured with these parameters.

```
restrict default noquery notrust nomodify notrap
```

I have tried stopping ntpd, doing a ntpdate -s/-u then starting ntpd again. It appears to adjust the clock at the time I run ntpdate, but refuses to sync up via the service. Everything just remains stratum 16 indefinitely.

Comment: What kernel version and from where? Also have you double check any firewall/security configs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to peer server configuration. Removing that allowed it to sync up with upstream servers.